# Technical historical books covering the Apollo-Saturn program

Tags: apollo-program, history, saturn-v, reference-request

In the preface of "Stages to Saturn", the author Robert E. Bilstein writes:

> This book is a technological history. [...] Two other histories, already published, deal with subjects keyed to the Apollo Saturn Program: (1) the development of the Apollo command and service modules along with the lunar module and (2) the construction and operation of launch facilities at Cape Kennedy.

What are the two books he is referring to?

---

*Stages to Saturn* NASA SP-4206 (1979) By Robert E. Bilstein ([web version](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/sp4206.htm)) ([pdf version](https://strives-uploads-prod.s3.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/19970009949/19970009949.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIASEVSKC45ZTTM42XZ&Expires=1600091200&Signature=v2xL%2BXjdqxq0JgNXIgYoc2WxDZI%3D))

---

[image: preview]
([preview at Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=JnoZTbVLx0MC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Chariots for Apollo* NASA SP-4205 (1979) By Courtney G. Brooks, James M. Grimwood and Loyd S. Swenson, Jr. ([web version](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4205/contents.html)) ([pdf version](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4205.pdf))

*Moonport* NASA SP-4204 (1978) By Charles D. Benson and William Barnaby Faherty ([web version](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4204/contents.html)) ([pdf version](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19790003956/downloads/19790003956.pdf))

Comment: I suspected *Moonport* was one of them, thanks for confirming and pointing to *Chariots*. I'll add links to web and PDF versions of *Stages to Saturn* to my post.

Comment: @Ludo I'll add them to the "resources" meta post as well. *Stages* is already there but I'll add the other link you found. https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/250/6944

Comment: The second reference could also be [*The Kennedy Space Center Story*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19710024295).

Comment: Looking at the sequence of report ids I think @organic marble is correct.